# How to rename a column that is found using str_detect in r?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I want to replace one column name from dataframe so that I can then update the values in that column. However, I'm open to alternative and better ways to do this if someone can show me how to do that.

> Find column name that starts with Org and ends with Type. Sometimes dataframe for different source may have a different column name. Also, it'd be nice to make it case insensitive**

```
org_type_col <- names(assessment) %>% str_subset("(Org)(.*)(Type)") 
assessment <- assessment %>% setNames(org_type_col = "OrgType")
```

But this is where I'm running into error. The error I get is this:

```
Error in setNames(., org_type_col = "OrgType") : unused argument (org_type_col = "OrgType")
```

I want to rename the column so that I can do the following:

```
### Organization Type

assessment <- assessment %>% 
  add_column(OrganizationType = case_when(
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Health")) ~ "Healthcare", 
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Pharmaceuticals")) ~ "Pharmaceuticals",
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Banking|Financial|Insurance")) ~ "Financial Services",
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Computer|Telecommunication")) ~ "High-Tech",
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Energy|Utilities")) ~ "Energy",
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Education")) ~ "Education",
(str_detect(.$OrgType, "Government")) ~ "Government")) %>%
replace_na(list(OrgType = "Unknown"))
```

Is there an easier and better way to do this to combine them all?

Comment: If you're using `dplyr`, use `rename` instead of `setNames`. (`setNames` is a base function that expects you to provide all the names, not just a single replacement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can do :

```
names(assessment)[grepl('^Org.*Type$', names(assessment), ignore.case = TRUE)] <- 'OrgType'
```

If you are interested in `tidyverse` solution you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

assessment %>%
  rename_with(~str_detect(.,regex('^Org.*Type$', ignore_case = TRUE)), 'OrgType')
```

Comment: Tidyverse approach only changed the column name to `TRUE` instead of OrgType, but the base R approach worked fine. Thanks